# .on('click' function not always firing - often takes 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form validation script, which should fire upon clicking the submit button. Everything works well, except sometimes it requires the submit button to be clicked twice before going. The fact is only happens about 20% of the time makes it really hard to diagnose. The #send button is not dynamic, so I'm not sure what the issue could be. Any help would be appreciated! This will be used on a mobile form, so any ideas for any other improvements as well would be great. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var jVal = {

    'location' : function() {

        var element = $('#location');

        var errorMsg = $('#LocationError');

        if(element.val()==0) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            errorMsg.slideUp('fast');
                element.removeClass('wrong');
        }
    },

    'firstName' : function() {

        var element = $('#firstname');

        var errorMsg = $('#nameInfo');

        if(element.val().length < 1) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            errorMsg.slideUp('fast');
                element.removeClass('wrong');
        }
    },

    'lastName' : function() {

        var element = $('#lastname');

        var errorMsg = $('#LastNameInfo');          

        if(element.val().length < 1) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            errorMsg.slideUp('fast');
                element.removeClass('wrong');
        }
    },


    'email' : function() {

        var element = $('#email');

        var errorMsg = $('#EmailError');

        var patt = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if(element.val().length < 1) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.html('Email is required.').slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else if (!patt.test(element.val())) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.html('Please enter a valid email address.').slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            errorMsg.slideUp('fast');
                element.removeClass('wrong');
        }
    },

    'telephone' : function() {
        var element = $('#telephone');

        var errorMsg = $('#TelephoneInfo');

        var patt = /^(?:\+?1[-. ]?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/;


        if(element.val().length < 1) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.html('Telephone is required.').slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else if (!patt.test(element.val())) {
            jVal.errors = true;
                errorMsg.html('Please enter a valid telephone number.').slideDown('fast');
                element.addClass('wrong');
        } else {
                errorMsg.slideUp('fast');                   
                element.removeClass('wrong');
        }
    },

    'sendIt' : function (){

        var element = $('#send'),
            submissionInfo = '<div id="SubmissionInfo" class=""></div>',
            successMSG = '<strong>Thank you for contacting us!</strong><br>An Ideal Image consultant will contact you soon!</i>',
            sending = '<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-2x" style="color:#5383b4;"></i>',
            errors = $('.error');


        if($("#SubmissionInfo").length==0) {
        $(element).before(submissionInfo);
        }

        submissionInfo = $('#SubmissionInfo');


        if(!jVal.errors) {

            //form.submit();

            var form = $('#myform'),
                trackingURL = window.location.pathname+'thankyou.php';  

            submissionInfo.html(sending).fadeIn('fast');

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    form.get(0).reset();
                    submissionInfo.html(successMSG).addClass('success');    
                    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview',trackingURL]);
                    jVal.firePixel();                   
                }
            });

        } else {
        errors.animate({marginLeft:'+='+5},150,function(){$(this).animate({marginLeft:'-='+5},150);});

        }

    },

    'firePixel' : function() {
        //Chango
        var __chconv__ = {"conversion_id":14};
        (function() {
            if (typeof(__chconv__) == "undefined") return;
                var e = encodeURIComponent; var p = [];
            for(var i in __chconv__){p.push(e(i) + "=" + e(__chconv__[i]))}
            (new Image()).src = document.location.protocol + '//as.chango.com/conv/i;' + (new Date()).getTime() + '?' + p.join("&");
        })();

        //VWO
         if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == "function") {
        // Code for Custom Goal: Goal #2
         _vis_opt_goal_conversion(200);
        // uncomment the following line to introduce a half second pause to ensure goal always registers with the server
        _vis_opt_pause(500);
        }
    }
};

// ====================================================== //

// Validation
$('#send').on('click', function (){
        jVal.errors = false;
        jVal.location();
        jVal.firstName();
        jVal.lastName();
        jVal.telephone();
        jVal.email();
        jVal.sendIt();
    return false;
});

$('#location').change(jVal.location);
$('#firstname').change(jVal.firstName);
$('#lastname').change(jVal.lastName);
$('#email').change(jVal.email);
$('#telephone').change(jVal.telephone);


});
```

EDIT: I think I figured it out that it's my button style. If I click on the top 2px of the button, the click doesn't fire. Any idea how to fix this?

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .75em 0 .75em;
    margin: 4px 0;
    height: 3.25em;
    background: #e45c5e;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #9f4042 0 4px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: #9f4042 0 4px 0 0;
    box-shadow: #9f4042 0 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 3.25;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    outline: 0;
}



.button:hover, .button:focus {
    background-color: #f16d6f;
}


.button:active {
    top: 0;
    background-color: #f16d6f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #9f4042 0 2px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: #9f4042 0 2px 0 0;
    box-shadow: #9f4042 0 2px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce the code to a bare minimum example to isolate the issue.

Comment: `jQuery().val()` may also return `null` - then checking `length` property on null throws a uncaught error (see your console). use instead `if (!element.val())` that's the same as `.length == 0`, `== ""`, `== 0` and the other falsy values compared with double equals implicit type coersion.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to do that. I'm not seeing any error in my console though from it?

Comment: probably the `top: -2px;` are a trouble for some browsers, or it's slipping under another element, did you try adding `z-index: +1`? also try to wrap the button with a `div` or `span` with which you do the `display: inline-block; position: relative; top: -2px;`! (i thought of an exception that may break your closures before doing sendIt.)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use:

```
$('#send').on('click', function (){
console.log('done a click')
...
```

and Firebug or something else to know if the event is read

Comment: This happens so rarely it's tough to pinpoint, but highly frustrating when it does. I tried re creating it with minimal styles and I got it to happen once, and it didn't record the click until I pressed it a second time.

Comment: I know it's may a stupid answer, but are you sure it isn't your mouse?

Comment: Or try to put your validation function inside your ready function

Answer (score 0):

One of the other functions prior to the sendIt function is probably failing it's routine sometimes. Try using a debug tool like firebug to see what errors happen. If there are no errors, add some console.log lines to isolate the issue.

Comment: i think I figured it out. It has to do with my button styles. If the click is on the top 2px of the button, the click doesn't fire.